# phoenix sql timeout to execute count query with 30 million records on hbase table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have one `hbase` table that has 30 million records. I want to paginate the records on web application but when I execute `phoenix` `sql` query it takes 55 seconds or sometime timeouts. How to fix this?

Comment: You can increase the timeouts, that's what we did.  We ended up with ~300 seconds - data.tx.timeout https://phoenix.apache.org/tuning.html

Comment: @PaulBastide thanks for reply & one more thing I want to use data for real time disaply on my web application dashboard. If it will take 55 seconds to find only count then it will not useful for user friendly so any other solution for this ?

Comment: you may want to use 'select count(SINGLE_COLUMN) from table' or mapreduce - hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter mytable --- they both say they take time.  an alternative you could take is to add a sequence column, and just check the state of the sequence, instead of counting.